# How can i use Swift mailer in my php code in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using this but i am getting error

```
foo_bundle.listener.comment:
        class: xxx\Listener\CupleListener
        arguments: [@mailer]
```

---

```
class CupleListener
{
    protected $mailer;

    public function __construct(Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    public function onCenterEvent(CupleEvent $event)
    {
        $center = $event->getcenter();

            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('New comment posted on ' . $post->getTitle())
            ->setFrom('send@example.com')
            ->setTo('xxxxxxxxxx')
            ->setBody("Hey, somebody left a new comment on a post you're subscribed to! It says: " . $comment->getBody());
            $this->mailer->send($message);

    }
}
```

This is giving error

Also i don't know which class to include on the top of namespace

Comment: It said Expecting instance of Mybundle\Swif_mailer but instance of Swiftmailer given

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with:

```
public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
}
```